# How to get avg between two values in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Please refer to the details shown here:

```
 ID  Value   
 ---------
 1    120 
 1    150
```

Query :

```
 Select avg(value) 
 from table 
 group by Id
```

Current output = `130`

Expected output =

```
120 + 150 / 2 = 135
```

Please let me know your comments.

Comment: Can't reproduce - I **do get** 135 - as expected .....

Comment: Is there something you are omitting? In this simple reproduction of your scenario I get 135 as expected: `SELECT AVG(value) FROM (VALUES(1, 120), (1, 150)) t (id, value) GROUP BY Id `

Comment: Why only 150/2 and not 120/2?  Which is logic behind it?

Comment: Its actually 120+150=270/2=135

Comment: In that case check my answer

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server does integer arithmetic, even for integers.  However, it doesn't round integers to the nearest 10.  Perhaps on your real data, the following will do what you want:

```
Select avg(value * 1.0) 
from table 
group by Id ;
```

It changes the value to something with a decimal point, so the average is not an integer average.